# What happens when a server without SSL makes an HTTPS request to a server that does?

Tags: security, ssl, server

In these instances, what happens?  Does communication fall back to HTTP?  I'm assuming that communication will either fail, or fallback, depending on the setup of the ssl-enabled destination server.

Example Case:

A plugin that is installed on Server A (which may or may not have SSL), communicates with an API that functions over HTTPS on Server B.

Comment: A server without SSL *can't* make an HTTPS request. It doesn't make sense. And why wouldn't server A have SSL?

Comment: I certainly hope it would have SSL!  But I was thinking about this and started to wonder.

Let me expand on my Example Case...

A plugin is created that has a PHP file which POSTs data to an external API (its endpoints are HTTPS).  The plugin is installed on any number of servers -- some of which I am assuming may not have SSL.  If it is installed on a server that doesn't support SSL, would communication simply not happen?  Is this safe to assume, or is there a risk of server B falling back to HTTP and exposing the POSTed data?

Comment: First find me a server that doesn't support SSL PHP clients. Then we'll know whether we're actually talking about anything. As to what happens, it is entirely up to how server B behaves. If it's so poorly written or configured that it allows fallback to HTTP, it will fallback. I find the whole scenario utterly improbable.

Comment: Thank your for your comments EJP.  I was basing my assumption that there may be servers out there that don't support SSL.  Given your remarks, I can now assume that such a case is highly unlikely.  I appreciate your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is not clear enough. Do you mean, with "a server without SSL", that

- The server system has no kind of SSL software installed. In this case of course no SSL requests can be done from the server.
- Or that the web server itself is only available by HTTP and not HTTPS, but there is a script on it which needs to access other hosts by HTTPS. In this case it can do these requests if the required software is installed on the server and if the target host is available by HTTPS and if no firewalls blocks the connections etc. Configuration of the web server itself has nothing to do what kind of requests programs on the web server can do.

Comment: Thanks Steffen -- this answers my question.  To be honest, I didn't really know what "a server without SSL" would look like -- maybe it didn't have openSSL, etc. installed, or maybe it lacked its own cert which would prevent it from communicating via SSL.  Your bullet points address both.  I am familiar with client<->server ssl, but not server<->server, and wanted to make sure I wasn't making any unsafe assumptions and was not able to track down detailed explanations of how this might play out.
Thank you as well for your response!

Comment: There is no server<->server SSL. If you access an https server from an application on a server, this server behaves as a client regarding this connection. The distinction is usually, that a server application accepts connections (from a client), while a client application creates a new connection (to the server).